# An error is occuring when I am installing my Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

When I am installing the Android Studio from the official website then it is showing the error when I start the setup. The message is:

> javax.net.ssl.SSSLEXCEPTION: Tag Mismatched

Image reference is given:

[image: Error screenshot]